# ORDER BY maximum with grouped by

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, criteria, jpql

With following table,

```
RECORD
---------------------
NAME            VALUE
---------------------
   Bill Clinton   100
   Bill Clinton    95
   Bill Clinton    90
Hillary Clinton    90
Hillary Clinton    95
Hillary Clinton    85
Monica Lewinsky    70
Monica Lewinsky    80
Monica Lewinsky    90
```

Can I, with JPA(JPQL or Criteria), select following output?

```
   Bill Clinton   100
Hillary Clinton    95
Monica Lewinsky    90
```

I mean, `ORDER BY` maximum `VALUE` group by `NAME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query itself

```
SELECT  Name,
        MAX(value) value
FROM    record
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Value DESC
```

Output:

```
|            NAME | VALUE |
---------------------------
|    Bill Clinton |   100 |
| Hillary Clinton |    95 |
| Monica Lewinsky |    90 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb176/1)**

I'm not an expert in jpa but something between these lines might work

```
List<Object[]> results = entityManager
        .createQuery("SELECT  Name, MAX(value) maxvalue FROM record GROUP BY Name ORDER BY Value DESC");
        .getResultList();
for (Object[] result : results) {
    String name = (String) result[0];
    int maxValue = ((Number) result[1]).intValue();
}
```

Comment: "*with JPA(JPQL or Criteria)*"?

Answer (score 1):

Because JPQL queries operate to the entities, following mapping is assumed:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="your_table")
public class YourEntity {
    @Id private int id;
    private String name;
    private int value;
    ...
}
```

For such a mappings query is as follows:

```
SELECT e.name, MAX(e.value)
FROM YourEntity e
GROUP BY e.name
ORDER BY MAX(e.value) DESC
```

Results of such a query is List of object arrays. First element in array is name and second element is value (as in select).

Answer (score 1):

Using Criteria:

```java
CriteriaQuery<Person> q = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> p = q.from(Person.class);
q.select(p.get("name"), cb.max(p.get("value")));
q.groupBy(p.get("name"));
q.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.max(p.get("value"))));
```